# Controle de IPs com Excel + VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, redes

Estou construindo algumas funções para analise de uma tabela de IPs. Acabei de usar VBA pela primeira vez na vida e em minhas pesquisas não encontrei nada que pudesse me ajudar.

Preciso criar uma função que busque o menor número inexistente em uma coluna no Excel. O usuário deverá passar o valor inicial e final, por exemplo 5777 e 6287. A função deverá buscar na coluna predeterminada (que estará ordenada) entre estes índices e, ao encontrar um índice não existente, informá-lo ao usuário.

Estes índices representam uma transformação no IP e o intervalo entre eles representa um subrede. Quando ele me retor o menor índice disponível, a transformação inversa me mostrará o menor IP livre naquele intervalo.

Eu sei que poderia criar iterações a partir do índice inicial e a cada iteração comparar o índice com todos os índices disponíveis. Só que isso precisaria de duas iterações e no caso de não haver endereços disponíveis, ele faria m^n (m = qtd de IPs utilizados em toda a rede e n = quantidade IPs na subrede). Isso, pra uma subrede de 512 IPs seria um número absurdo de iterações.

Haveria alguma outra forma de fazer isto sem onerar muito a execução do código?

Comment: Não entendi a parte do "ao encontrar um índice não existente, informá-lo ao usuário.", poderia explicar melhor o que quis dizer?

Comment: O índice nada mais é que um IP de forma mais "computável". Um dos problemas que tenho é que os IPs estão dispersoss dentro do intervalo da subrede. Isso dificulta muito o gerenciamento.
O objetivo dessa função é fazer com que as novas máquinas tapem os buracos assumindo IPs menores. Ou seja, quero aumentar a concentração de máquinas no começo do intervalo.
Fiz-me mais claro?

Comment: Para ilustrar, uma das subredes daqui tem 510 endereços, em tese. Utilizo apenas 246 deles. As máquinas deveriam se concentrar na primeira metade e assim seria fácil achar um endereço livre: ele seria sempre o último utilizado +1. Na minha atual situação, os técnicos pensam um número e chutam até acertar.
Como não posso obrigar o técnico a fazer uma pesquisa pelo menor IP disponível (isso demandaria muito tempo), quero que o sistema indique o melhor endereço para ele. Dessa forma, em algum tempo, teremos a situação ideal de os IPs estarem em um intervalo contínuo.

Comment: Se eu bem entendi, em tese, você nem sequer necessitaria usar VBA para isso. Se ninguém mais se pronunciar, mais tarde posto uma "possível" solução para o problema proposto.

Comment: Não espere não, estou precisando disso com certa urgência.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja na imagem se isso seria suficiente.

Para facilitar eventual colagem, a fórmula é:

```
=SE(É.NÃO.DISP(PROCV( <número de IP da lista completa>; <lista de IPs já utilizados, pode ser um intervalo nomeado>; 1; FALSO)); "Texto para Livre"; "Texto para em uso")
```

Detalhe, apesar de você citar que a listagem de IPs em uso está em ordem crescente, do modo que a fórmula foi configurada, isso não tem importância.

[image: Recorte de planilha de exemplo]

Comment: Sim, não é tão elaborado quanto o que eu havia imaginado mas resolve e é bastante eficiente.
Muito obrigado!

Comment: Que bom que ajudou. De qualquer forma, havendo necessidade, pode-se utilizar isso como base para algo mais "personalizado".